FIX Bitstamp logon message (MsgType = 'A') doesn't work
I'm using FIX 4.4, could anyone tell me what would be the correct FIX string to send to the Bitstamp exchange for authentication? After authentication do you receive a confirmation message from the server? I attach the link to the documentation https://www.bitstamp.net/fix/v2/#fix-logon. Thanks for collaboration
I tried to connect, but I don't understand if it's right or wrong because the server seems to continue to respond to me, but it responds with null messages. I tried sending a few more messages, which should have gotten me a response, after attempting to log in, but I got no results.

You've given us nothing to go on.  What FIX messages are sent/received?  Is your client sending a 35=A logon?  Does it receive a 35=A logon response?  What is a "null message"?  Are you using a FIX engine library (such as QuickFIX) or trying to write from scratch (super not-recommended)?
